# What is the logic to implement a one-to-one chat application using the Firestore database in android Studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am Building a chat application using Firestore database in Android studio. At the moment I have created a Fragment that displays a the list of users from the Firestore database. While I can create the chat activity that will open once you click on the user, I am unable to proceed as to how exactly should i send a message to that specific user. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph2KN.png) is the screenshot of the database of the various users, I think the unique ID of every user is the key to solving my issue but not sure once again how to implement.

Comment: Here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: Thank you but this is in kotlin and i am building it in java @alexmamo

Answer (score 1):

You should create third collection of messege where you should save the unique id of 
 messege and sender and receiver id these things are essential for any chat application
 and i am telling this because i have created chat application with firestore.

Structure :

```
   messege collection : messge1(document) : uniqueId :1254
                                     senderId :119
                                     receiverId :228
                                     timestamp : 564444 (if needed)

                 messge2(document) : uniqueId :12854
                                     senderId :11
                                     receiverId :22
                                     timestamp : 564444 (if needed)

                 messge3(document) : uniqueId :1254
                                     senderId :141
                                     receiverId :225     
                                     timestamp : 564444 (if needed)
```

Let me know if still stuck so we can find another solution.Happy Coding.

Comment: The sender id will be the id of the user logged in but how do i get the id for the receiver.

Comment: I am the user and i logged now i will see the list of user(ex all my friend list) so  when i click on user item to chat with them at that time i can get the id of that user and as i am clicking to user item thats simply means i am sender and the user i clicked to chat is the receiver.

Comment: Would you feel comfortable sharing the source code of your application? I was unable to find anyone who used Firestore databse for the chat app online, as i am a beginner in android programming

Comment: This will surly help you : https://github.com/mitchtabian/FirestoreChatApp

Comment: Will check it out and message u if i still have doubts,thanks

Comment: Okay, Now how do you fetch the chat data between, say sender Id 119  is logged in and open chat with id 117, because last time i check firebase has problem with fetching data with OR condition,tried with whereIn didt work